# I am calculating the Shannon entropy and stuck on this integral

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

I am calculating the Shannon entropy of $\left|\Psi_{+}\left(x_{+}\right)\right|^{2}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{3}_{+}\sqrt{2\pi}}x^{2}_{+}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^{2}_{+}}{2\sigma^{2}_{+}}\right\}$, which is given by
$$
H=-\int\left|\Psi_{+}\left(x_{+}\right)\right|^{2}\ln\left|\Psi_{+}\left(x_{+}\right)\right|^{2}dx.
$$
I am stuck on that. This is how I tried,

$
H=-\int Nx^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}\ln\left[Nx^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}\right]dx\quad,\textrm{ where }N\equiv\frac{1}{\sigma^{3}_{+}\sqrt{2\pi}}x^{2}_{+},a\equiv\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}_{+}},x\equiv x_{+}\\
=-N\int x^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}\left[\ln N+\ln x^{2}+\ln e^{-ax^{2}}\right]dx\\
=-N\ln N\int x^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}dx-N\int x^{2}\ln x^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}dx+Na\int x^{4}e^{-ax^{2}}dx
$

I have no clue to calculate the second term, $N\int x^{2}\ln x^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}dx$.

Please help me to solve the second term.

P.S. The answer of entropy $H$ is related to the Euler's constant. But this is the furthest I know.

Comment: (1)By $\ln x^2$ do you mean $(\ln x)^2$?.(2)The second term in any case cannot be expressed in terms of more elemental functions.

Comment: It is $\ln\left[x^{2}\right]$. And no. I have no idea how to deal with the second term. I am really stuck.

Comment: It would be easier to read, to replace it with $2\ln x.$ But the indefinite integral cannot be expressed in finite form in terms of elementary functions. Are you looking for approximations for the definite integral over a certain domain, or set of domains?

Comment: Yes, the integral is from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. I should have written it as $2N\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^{2}\ln xe^{-ax^{2}}dx$.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the answer, Mathematica gives \begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\log(x^2)\exp(-ax^2)\;dx = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 a^{3/2}}\left(\log(a)+\log(4)-2+\gamma\right), \;\; \text{Re}(a) > 0
\end{equation}
the antiderivative contained some large hypergeometric functions so it might be tricky to do it without a CAS.